# error when wanted to validate key on database

Tags: php

i had the problem when i want to check my valid key on my database and showing this error

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ravaaa\indexx.php on line 20

the db is login, tables is users (5) id,name,key,login

this the code

```
    $error='';
$key="123";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
if (mysqli_connect_error())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
  }
 echo "sukses\n\n";

 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE key='$key'");
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 if($rows == 1){
 echo "key is valid";
 }

 else
 {
 $error = "key is Invalid";
 echo $error;
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name `key` is a reserved word and therefore must be escaped using backticks:

```
select * from users WHERE `key` = '$key'
```

Without the escape, the query will fail and return `FALSE` per the [mysqli_query docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You can exit early with an error using the `or die` pattern:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `key` = '$key'")
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Check your column name (id) is exist or not  in your users table

Comment: it showing again like thismysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in....

is any problem with my query ?
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE key='$key'")

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='123'' at line 1

Comment: `key` should be surrounded with backticks (\`) because it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your table have an column named "key"? Key is a reserved MySQL Keyword, and when i tried to create a table with this column to test i got an error, and after change the name "key" to another name (on the table and on the .php) i got no errors, just the message "key is Invalid".

Try to change the column name "key" and change on the php too, and check if you still get errors.